# Does Unity have a built in pathfinding system?

Tags: unity

I know that there a lot of plugins available for pathfinding in unity but I was just wondering if unity has a built in pathfinding system ?

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497442/default-pathfinding-system-in-unity) across SE sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Unity does have a built in pathfinding system. Though there are a few features of the navmesh system that are pro only, like dynamic obstacles, avoidance priority configuration for navmesh agents, and off mesh links.

Byte56 provided a link to the written documentation. Here is the official video tutorial unity released: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mP7ulMu5UkU

Comment: Update: for those using Unity 5+ I believe the navmesh system is no longer a pro only feature.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You'll find resources for the Unity path finding system by searching for "Unity Navigation Meshes". You can find the documentation for it [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Navigation.html)